# How to programmatically calculate decomposability index of continuous Markov Chain

Tags: markov-process

I'm looking a way to calculate programmatically decomposability index of continuous Markov Chain. Could anyone post an example here or guide how to do it or give some code to show how it could be done.

Any help is appreciated!